# Использовать второй монитор силами java

Tags: java

Привет, суть вопроса, можно ли реализовать такое приложение:

Предположим что у нас два монитора на одном ПК, и неважно как они подключены к ПК, будь то одна видео карта с двумя ВГА, или будь то две видео карты, то есть по одной на каждый монитор, возможно любой вариант подключения, одни монитор у нас, наш рабочий, работаем с ним в штатном режиме, а вот со вторым работает java приложение, то есть банальная программка выводит сообщение на второй монитор, предположим на синем фоне "привет мир", реально?

если реально то какие есть идеи, предполагаю что надо капать в сторону winapi, хотя могу и ошибаться

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не вижу никаких проблем. В Swing'е получить хэндл на 2-й, 3-й и вообще любой дисплей не проблема:

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices(); //возвращает массив устройств
int numDislays=gs.length; //количество мониторов
```

Comment: ок, спс!

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html

Comment: При создании [`JFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#JFrame-java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration-) можно указать, на каком мониторе должно отображаться окно.